# How to change ng-dropdown-panel style in ng-select?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I want to change the ng-dropdown-panel style but its only styles the container.

components.css

```
.ng-select.dropdown ::ng-deep .ng-select-container  {            
    min-height: 0px;
    border-radius: 10;
    background-color: #343A40;
    color: white;    
}
.ng-select.dropdown ::ng-deep .ng-dropdown-panel  {            
    background-color: #343A40;
    color: white;    
}
```

component.html

```
<ng-select class="dropdown" [items]="data" bindLabel="data" bindValue="dbValue"></ng-select>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stq6ew

Comment: Explain your problem/requirement also in the question..